# combine fields to make new field sql

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

I have these three fields that I'd like to combine to make one new one:

```
DEPT  CRS  SC
-------------
BIO   101  A
BIO   101  B
BIO   105  A
CHEM  101  A
```

Preferred output:

```
NEW
-------------
BIO 101A
BIO 101B
BIO 105A
CHEM 101A
```

I have a feeling I would use NVL()?

Comment: Are you wanting a new column in a table or to display the values differently?

Comment: @Just Aguy, New column.

Comment: The answers are not adding a new column in a table.  It's a select as which is temporary and for displaying values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `select DEPT||" "||CRS||SC as new from table`

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this query

```
SELECT A.DEPT, A.CRS || A.SC AS NEWCOLUMN
FROM YOURTABLE A
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a view to make it easier to use in the future.

```
CREATE VIEW SUMMARY AS
SELECT DEPT || ' ' || CRS || SC AS NEWCOL
FROM YOURTABLE;
```